# Net 3.5 Machine Configuration

Tags: .net-3.5

Which Machine.Config is applicable for framework 3.5 assembly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config is the one..
(on Windows 2003)

Answer (score 0):

One of it is:

```
App.config
```